# Byobu cache or restored duplicate sessions

Tags: byobu

Every time I quit Byobu accidentally, on the next start I find an extra session *tab* for each session called **_{sessionname}-{id}**:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

I find this really annoying since this was not happening in my previous machine with an old Ubuntu 14. I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 now.

Also, i cant find a way to close these extra sessions windows without closing the original.

Pressing [<kbd>F6</kbd> (Detach session and then logout)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/byobu.1.html#keybindings) only regenerate the extra/duplicated session with a different **{id}**.

Comment: Seems [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1785639). Please set there if the bug also affects you. As [stated on official site](http://byobu.co/support.html) the place to report bugs is [in this Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu), not [that one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~byobu) (I don't know why that even exist).

Comment: @PabloBianchi exactly this

Comment: Possible workaround: Move to "original" session and run: `tmux kill-session -t "$(tmux ls | grep _ | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d:)"`.

Comment: @PabloBianchi man, that worked really great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This [appears to be a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1785639) in later versions of byobu**, caused when detaching or switching sessions. The bug has not been fixed yet...

Here is a workaround<sup>*</sup>. This command will get rid of the extra sessions. It was tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
# Get list of active sessions that start with an underscore, and kill them
tmux ls | grep ^_ | cut -f1 "-d:" | xargs -r tmux kill-session -t
```

This will get a list of `byobu`/`tmux` sessions, check for ones that start with an underscore, and then tell `tmux` to kill them. If there are no duplicate sessions, it won't do anything, so it's safe to run.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> [Pablo Bianchi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927187/byobu-cache-or-restored-duplicate-sessions#comment1862456_927187) posted a workaround as well, though the command they provided does not check that any duplicate session exists, so it can end up calling "tmux kill-session" without a target and end up killing your active session... It will also kill sessions that happen to have an underscore anywhere within the session name.</sup>

Comment: i didnt know about the cut command; i get it somehow selects the entries that after removing something match hyphen followed by any number of digits ?

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem and solved it by updating byobu from PPA.

> byobu 5.125 tmux 2.6 Ubuntu 18.04

I spent a few weeks using workaround (killing the process with tmux ls|grep ^_|...); then I fixed this issue completely by just updating byobu to 5.133:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install byobu
```

Comment: Nice, this was fixed over the last two years. Good update!!! The mentioned scripts is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are starting it and then exiting it, but keeping the session alive.

You can exit *byobu* closing the session (logout) at the same time using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

Also, you can switch between sessions using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>, and then close that session panes/windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, `exit` or your preferred method.

You can check *byoby*'s built in help using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

As a brute force approach, you can terminate all byobu's running sessions running `byobu kill-server` on your terminal before re-running `byobu`.

*Note:* [Dustin Kirkland](https://askubuntu.com/users/4733/dustin-kirkland), the creator of `byobu`, has a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/byobu/) where you can get newer versions before being released on primary channels.

Comment: nope. I open any terminal and then type byobu. Than start using it. if i close accidently the terminal and open a new one and then type byobu again : now i have two sessions. But both sessions share the same windows so if i close one window on one sessions, it closes in the other session two. It's like a duplicated session. The problem is if I have 4 sessions and quit, now i have 8 sessions.

Comment: how do you "accidentally" close byobu? Do you have byobu enabled at login (F9)? Also, when you said windows, did you refer to byobu-windows created with F2 or window manager windows?

Comment: by accidentally i mean :  alt f4 terminal or ctrl+shift+w on terminal (the terminal tab wich holds byobu) . I don't have byobu enabled at login. Yes, windows means f2 windows.

Comment: Ok, I think that's the intended behaviour _(if I don't close my shells, keep my session and all processes running)_. You can always navigate through open sessions with `Alt+Up/Down`. Also observed (at least on my machines) gnome-terminal asks to confirm closing a terminal with a running process. Anyway you are always able to terminate all byobu's running sessions running `byobu kill-server` on your terminal prior to re-running `byobu`.

Comment: Now we are getting close! I know i cant alt+up/down to navigate between my sessions. That's when the problems happens. Right there i have duplicated sessions for each one i had open before closing accidently.

Comment: Ok, seems I'm not able to reproduce your issue. You can also try with last version from [Dustin Kirkland's own ppa](https://launchpad.net/~byobu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to see if it's a fixed bug in newer releases.

Comment: Checked. It still happens :(